# нужна ли запятая перед "либо"?

Tags: пунктуация

Многие узнавали про это от старших членов семьи либо в школе от учителей.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не ставится между однородными дополнениями : Многие узнавали про это **от** старших **членов семьи либо** в школе **от учителей**.

[§86. Однородные члены, соединенные неповторяющимися союзами](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/43.htm#%D0%B7_04)

Между однородными членами предложения, связанными одиночными соединительными союзами и, да (в значении «и»), разделительными союзами или, либо, запятая не ставится,